# Discriminant of a splitting field

Tags: number-theory, field-theory

Let $f(x)\in\mathbf Q[x]$ and let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$. How is the discriminant of $K$ (as a number field) related to the discriminant of $f(x)$? Are they divisible by the same primes? Does one divide the other?